# Keycloak is not defined in angularjs 2 Example

Tags: typescript, angular, keycloak

I'm trying to implement keycloak into an angularjs 2 app (typescript).
I used the code from this [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app), but when I start the app I get:

```
Error: ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined(…)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added `keycloak.js` to your `index.html` ?

Comment: Yes, I have added keycloak.js

Comment: Without anymore code it is hard to determine. Perhaps provide a fiddle?

Comment: add `<script src="https://rawgit.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/master/dist/keycloak.min.js" ></script>`  taken from [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/blob/master/dist/keycloak.min.js)

Comment: that worked for me. Thx @Abdulrahman

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this one yet you can either modify the index.html to point to your keycloak js adapter nodejs installation.
Install

```
npm install keycloak-js-adapter
```

And then in Index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.js"></script>
```

Or it would be better to reference it directly from your keycloak installation. For latest 2.5.0.Final that's

```
<script src="KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script>
```

Of course the KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL is for example http://localhost:4400 or your domain name for keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

try to include this in the "`scripts`" section like below:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.js"]
```